# TabbedNotification function in jQuery not working when called using PHP echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a piece of PHP code where I want to call a jQuery function on page load, provided a variable is set.

Here is the code

```
<?php
     if(isset($_GET['msg']))
     {
          echo "<script>";
          echo "$(document).ready(function(){new TabbedNotification({
                              title: 'Tabbed Notificat',
                              text: '".$_GET['msg']."',
                              type: 'success',
                              sound: false
                          }); });";
          echo "</script>";
     }
     else
     {
          echo "";
     }
```

All the related css files, and js files have been attached prpoperly. The divs have also been created but somehow the tabbed notification is not working. Please help

Comment: Your question is incomplete and you will not get any helpful answer. You should show us the js your are included.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm ... it should work. To be sure if  correctly loaded TabbedNotification try first

> echo "console.log(TabbedNotification)";

or write a little test like this:

```
   <?php
  echo "function TabbedNotification(params){
          console.log(params);
       }";
  $_GET['msg'] = "test";
  echo "$(document).ready(function(){new TabbedNotification({
                          title: 'Tabbed Notificat',
                          text: '".$_GET['msg']."',
                          type: 'success',
                          sound: false
                      }); });";
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does TabbedNotification returns something? 
Maybe you should call something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var tN = new TabbedNotification({
    title: 'Tabbed Notificat',
    text: '".$_GET['msg']."',
    type: 'success',
    sound: false
  });

  tN.someMethod();
});
```

Can you show the code of TabbedNotification?

Comment: No @quanton81, TabbedNotification does not return anything

Comment: You say "tabbed notification is not working". What does that mean exactly? Did you try the hint from @MTK